# Adding OR condition to filter returns no results

Tags: javascript

I am using a `filter`, before a `map` to create a tree-like structure.

With the following snippet it correctly returns me the data I want:

```
  const nest = (tree, cod = basenode, link = 'link_id') =>
    (tree.filter(item => (item[link].toUpperCase() == cod.toUpperCase())).map(item => ({ ...item, productstructures: [{ operations: [{ materials: nest(tree, item.cod) }] }] })));
```

However, adding the OR condition to the `filter` function it returns no results. Shouldn't the OR condition, at least, give me the exact same results?

```
  const nest = (tree, cod = basenode, link = 'link_id') =>
    (tree.filter(item => (item[link].toUpperCase() == cod.toUpperCase())||(item[link]=="")).map(item => ({ ...item, productstructures: [{ operations: [{ materials: nest(tree, item.cod) }] }] })));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would we know without seeing your input array?

Comment: Provide input array.

Comment: Try wrapping the whole filter condition between parenthesis

Comment: Need to see what is input and what should be output! But you are doing operation on an array twice! first filter then map, You need to combine them using ```Array.reduce``` to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch of parenthesis use this and let me know if it helps.

```
const nest = (tree, cod = basenode, link = 'link_id') =>
    (tree.filter(item =>( (item[link].toUpperCase() == cod.toUpperCase()) ||(item[link]=="") ) ).map(item => ({ ...item, productstructures: [{ operations: [{ materials: nest(tree, item.cod) }] }] })));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work Like, I try with some dummy object like

```
let tree= [{abc:1,cd:2},{abc:2,cd:2},{abc:1,cd:3},{abc:3,cd:3}]

console.log(tree.filter(item => (item.abc==1 || item.abc== 2)))
```